# Oracle Discoverer BI: how to use DECODE into a calculation with a SUM

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to use DECODE on a SUM field ?
For example, something like this :

```
DECODE( SUM("QTA' CONV SUM 1 2 2"),'>0',1,'=0',0)
```

Comment: you need to use `CASE` here or `SIGN` with `DECODE` and `GREATEST` like Ed and David suggested. i would use `CASE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to @EdGibbs, if the values that you're summing are integers:

```
Greatest(Sum(...),1)
```

If you had negatives to contend with then maybe:

```
Least(Greatest(Sum(...),1),0)
```

The syntax gets a bit gnarly so if you did want to stick with Decode or Case then:

```
Case Sum(...)
  When 0 Then 0
  Else 1
End
```

... or ...

```
Decode(Sum(...),0,0,Sum(...))
```

I wouldn't go for a solution that repeats the Sum() though. Keep it [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, where you want the result to be `1` if the `SUM` is greater than zero or `0` if the `SUM` is zero, you can use the Oracle `SIGN` function. I'm not sure if there's any special Discoverer syntax, but outside of Discoverer I'd do it something like this:

```
SIGN(SUM(whatever you're summing))
```

The "techonthenet" site documents the function [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/sign.php).